# python library to generate pulse frequency of "n" hz

Tags: python, c, pigpio

I'm trying to make a function which would output a pulse frequency , given a Ts (time.sleep(ts) on my function) The function is for later use on an acceleration ramp for a stepper motor , as the driver works on a pulse train ,right now I made a function which sets an output to low and high with a time.sleep between them , and it works , however viewed on an osciloscope , it is not as exact as I would like

this is my python code

```
def ts_2_freq( ts ):
    #GPIO.output(self.pin_direccion , direccion)
    print("Funcionando con Ts={}".format(ts))
    for i in xrange(0,1):

        GPIO.output(self.pin_pulse,False)
        time.sleep(ts)
        GPIO.output(self.pin_pulse,True)
        time.sleep(ts)

for i in xrange(1000,1,-1):
    ts_2_freq(0.005)
```

which outputs the following pulse train

[image]

As you can see the pulse isnt on time every 5ms as expected , so I was hoping a C library would make it , but I need to be able to call it via python , as my whole code is on python (this code later comunicates to a python gui on tkinter)

this code would be used in 2 ways , setting an acceleration ramp (calling it multiple times) , and to give the motor an aproximate velocity based on pulse frequency , this is later corrected by a PID controller 
any help on a library that generates me this , also other ideas to solve it are welcome .
I made some tests modifying the pigpio PWM frequency , but it has specific steps , and I cannot set an intemediate frequency

```
>>> pi.set_PWM_frequency(26,1000)
1000L
>>> pi.set_PWM_frequency(26,1020)
1000L
>>> pi.set_PWM_frequency(26,1030)
1000L
>>> pi.set_PWM_frequency(26,1050)
1000L
>>> pi.set_PWM_frequency(26,1100)
1000L
>>> pi.set_PWM_frequency(26,1500)
1600L
>>> pi.set_PWM_frequency(26,1200)
1000L
>>> pi.set_PWM_frequency(26,1400)
1600L
>>>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

researching joans python code , I managed to build a simple program to manage a ramp on a pulse/direction drver , it seems to work , I just need to add dynamic behavior so that it behaves according to mi stepper max acceleration , and fit it depending on the time I need it to work , but I consider that my question is answered , thanks Joan , the more I ask the more I like your amazing library

```
import time
import pigpio
import math as m 

GPIO=26
velocity = input('velocity (mm/s): ')
wid = [0]*10
perimeter = 40*m.pi
dist_p_step = perimeter/2000  #perimeter of mi roller , divided by steps needed for it to make 1 complete revolution
pulses = velocity/dist_p_step

num_ts = 2*pulses
ts = 1./num_ts       
us = ts*1000000       
pi = pigpio.pi() # Connect to local Pi.
print ts       
pi.set_mode(GPIO, pigpio.OUTPUT);
for i in range(10):
    pi.wave_add_generic([
       pigpio.pulse(0,1<<GPIO,us*(10-(i))),
       pigpio.pulse(1<<GPIO,0,us*(10-(i)))]);

    wid[i] = pi.wave_create();

pi.wave_chain([
    255, 0,                       # loop start
    wid[0],                       #run wave
    255, 1, 3, 0,                 #end loop , repeat 3 times
    255, 0,                       # loop start
    wid[1],                       #run wave
    255, 1, 3, 0,
    255, 0,                       # loop start
    wid[2],                       #run wave
    255, 1, 3, 0,
    255, 0,                       # loop start
    wid[3],                       #run wave
    255, 1, 3, 0,
    255, 0,                       # loop start
    wid[4],
    255, 1, 3, 0,
    255, 0,                       # loop start
    wid[5],
    255, 1, 3, 0,
    255, 0,                       # loop start
    wid[6],
    255, 1, 3, 0,
    255, 0,                       # loop start
    wid[7],
    255, 1, 10, 0,
    255, 0,                       # loop start
    wid[8],
    255, 1, 3, 0,
    255,0,
    wid[9],    
    255,1,255,0                   #end loop repeat 255 times

   ])

while pi.wave_tx_busy():
    time.sleep(0.1);
for wave in wid: 
    pi.wave_delete(wave)

pi.stop()
```

Comment: Well done with the code.  One thing to note is that the current library is dimensioned for a maximum of ten loop counters per wave chain.  It's the sort of limit you might reach if building a ramp.

Comment: ok , si if I want a continous frequency , i should put pi.wave_chain(...) inside a loop?

Comment: If you want a continuous frequency make the last wave in the chain an infinite repeat, i.e. 255 0 last_wave_id 255 3

Answer (score 3):

Actually the pigpio Python module can do this quite easily for a single stepper.

You would use the wave functions in combination with wave chains.

Say you want a ramp of 20ms, 10ms, 5ms, 2ms, 1ms.

You could create separate waves with 10ms on 10 ms off, 5 ms on 5 ms off, ..., 500 µs on, 500 µs off.  You could then use a wave chain to send the first wave 100 times, the second 90 times, the third x times, etc.

Here is some code which may help show the sort of thing I mean.  It is for a stepper driver which requires pulsing the separate stepper coils.  If you are using a pulse/direction stepper driver it would be quite a bit simpler.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pigpio # http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html

class stepper:
   """
   A stepper class to return step pulses.
   """

   def __init__(self, pi, g1, g2, g3, g4, delay=1000):
      """
      """
      self._pi = pi

      self._g1 = g1
      self._g2 = g2
      self._g3 = g3
      self._g4 = g4

      self._delay = delay

      self._all = (1<<g1 | 1<<g2 | 1<<g3 | 1<<g4)

      self._g1_mode = pi.get_mode(g1)
      self._g2_mode = pi.get_mode(g2)
      self._g3_mode = pi.get_mode(g3)
      self._g4_mode = pi.get_mode(g4)

      pi.set_mode(g1, pigpio.OUTPUT)
      pi.set_mode(g2, pigpio.OUTPUT)
      pi.set_mode(g3, pigpio.OUTPUT)
      pi.set_mode(g4, pigpio.OUTPUT)

      self._forward_wid = None
      self._backward_wid = None

      self._forward_wave_init(delay)
      self._backward_wave_init(delay)

   def _step_on(self, pos):
      if   pos == 0: return (1<<self._g4)
      elif pos == 1: return (1<<self._g3 | 1<<self._g4)
      elif pos == 2: return (1<<self._g3)
      elif pos == 3: return (1<<self._g2 | 1<<self._g3)
      elif pos == 4: return (1<<self._g2)
      elif pos == 5: return (1<<self._g1 | 1<<self._g2)
      elif pos == 6: return (1<<self._g1)
      elif pos == 7: return (1<<self._g4 | 1<<self._g1)
      else:          return 0

   def _step_off(self, pos):
      return self._step_on(pos) ^ self._all

   def _forward_wave_init(self, delay):
      if self._forward_wid is not None:
         self._pi.wave_delete(self._forward_wid)
         self._forward_wid = None

      p=[] # pulses to drive stepper 1 cycle forward

      for i in range(8):
         p.append(pigpio.pulse(self._step_on(i), self._step_off(i), delay))

      self._pi.wave_add_generic(p)

      self._forward_wid = self._pi.wave_create()

   def _backward_wave_init(self, delay):
      if self._backward_wid is not None:
         self._pi.wave_delete(self._backward_wid)
         self._backward_wid = None

      p=[] # pulses to drive stepper 1 cycle backward

      for i in range(8):
         p.append(pigpio.pulse(self._step_on(7-i), self._step_off(7-i), delay))

      self._pi.wave_add_generic(p)

      self._backward_wid = self._pi.wave_create()

   def forward_wid(self):
      return self._forward_wid

   def backward_wid(self):
      return self._backward_wid

   def set_delay(self, delay):
      self._forward_wave_init(delay)
      self._backward_wave_init(delay)

   def cancel(self):
      self._pi.wave_delete(self._forward_wid)
      self._pi.wave_delete(self._backward_wid)

      self._pi.set_mode(self._g1, self._g1_mode)
      self._pi.set_mode(self._g2, self._g2_mode)
      self._pi.set_mode(self._g3, self._g3_mode)
      self._pi.set_mode(self._g4, self._g4_mode)

if __name__ == "__main__":

   import time

   pi = pigpio.pi()

   pi.wave_clear()

   delay = 2000

   s1 = stepper(pi,  2,  3,  4, 17, delay)
   s2 = stepper(pi, 14, 15, 18, 23, delay)

   for i in range(5):

      pi.wave_chain([
         255, 0, s1._forward_wid, s2._backward_wid, 255, 1, 0, 2,
         255, 0, s2._forward_wid, s1._backward_wid, 255, 1, 0, 2,
         ])

      while pi.wave_tx_busy():
         time.sleep(0.1)

      delay -= 200

      s1.set_delay(delay)
      s2.set_delay(delay)

   s1.cancel()
   s2.cancel()

   pi.stop()
```

Comment: Yes my stepper has a pulse/direction driver , so trying to understand your library , I should instantiate a wave , with 2 pulses (on and off , ) and a delay , something like
for i in range(1):

   pi.wave_add_generic([
      pigpio.pulse(1<<GPIO, 0, 200),
      pigpio.pulse(0, 1<<GPIO, (i+1)*200)]);

   wid[i] = pi.wave_create();
and then and then send them with wave chain command??